# how to integrate a 'template' in my own html/javascript project

Tags: node.js, mosaic

I am working in a society, and we are developing an interface with HTML, PHP and JavaScript for customers. This interface must be able to let users create emails, so they must pass some information. So I suggested: why not integrate a template that offer this "email managing"?

And then I found a template, I didn't get the global functioning of it but it's sound very interesting to me the name of the template is `mosaico.io` and the link is [here](https://mosaico.io/editor.html#6ogvxwp).

So my question is that how can I integrate it into my project? Just like any other template (bootstrap, metronic etc ...) and definitely use it.